# Weights of Mask R-CNN working on certain computers but not on others

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Mask R-CNN to obtain instance segmentation in my own dataset. The training process seems to be successful since the predictions seem to make sense. Nevertheless, I've encountered an unexpected issue. When I evaluate the results from training in different computers using the exact same files, hyperparameters, and weights, the predictions make no sense in certain cases. I tested them in four different computers (and in both Ubuntu and Windows) and in two of them, I obtain results such as the ones presented in the attached images.
I really don't understand what the issue can be. Has anybody encountered something like this?

Please find the images here:

[image]
[image]
[image]